# Delete from a table which has a foreign key mvc 5.

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc

I have two tables Lift

```
public class Lift()
{
  [Key]
  public int LiftID { get; set; }
  public string StartPoint { get; set; }
  public virtual List<RequestLift> requestLifts { get; set; }
}
```

Then a RequestLift table

```
public class RequestLift()
{
  [Key]
  public int RequestLiftID { get; set; }
  public int DriverID { get; set; }
}
```

DriverID is a foreign key to LiftID. I want to be able to delete a lift and so request lift with it. In my controller I have

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            //if (id == null)
            //{
            //    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            //}

            Lift lift = db.Lifts.Find(id);
            db.Lifts.Remove(lift);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Then in my identity models

```
    public DbSet<Lift> Lifts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WeeklyLift> weeklyLifts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RequestLift> requestLifts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Lift>()
          .HasOptional(l => l.requestLifts)
          .WithMany()
          .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)
    }
```

However an unhandled exception error occurs when I try to delete something that contains a key in both tables.

Comment: what is the exception message?

Comment: DBUpdateException was unhandled by user code

Comment: And the inner exception?

Comment: Sorry @Nico I got it. My own silly mistake thanks for your time